# Step up converter

Tags: voltage, boost, converter, output, code

I built a circuit of boost converter and my input voltages is 6-9 V. I want to get output at the converter 9-12 V. My problem is that I get over 40 V and I do not know why, in the code do I have to set the range of the DC that I have in the calculations?
Or I just increase the duty cycle from 0 to 100? Or my problem would be something else?

[image]

"BOOST CONVERTER1-schematic in multisim"

Comment: Hi, it depends on many things. Could you show your schematic ? Also, what is the load of your boost converter ?

Comment: Please edit to include the schematic and if possible a photo of the circuit as built. SMPS like this can be sensitive to construction details and choice of components. Which controller IC are you using?

Comment: I am using the Raspberry Pi

Comment: Can you try reducing the resistance and tell us the result? Also the current you are using at the moment should be 40mA or aproximately this much. I suggest removing the diode and adding the transistor in series instead.

Comment: I changed the resistance it doesnt change much , why i need to remove the diode and put instead transistor?

Comment: What's your feedback?

Answer (score 1):

If I did not do mistakes, your boost converter is working in DCM as regards of your load your inductance and your frequency. Here is the formula (considering perfect components) which gives you the limit on your current load between CCM (Continuous Current Mode) and DCM (Discontinuous Current Mode) :

$$\frac{Vin*Vin*T}{2*L*Vout}*(1-\frac{Vin}{Vout}) = Ilim$$

Then, once you know in which mode works your converter, you can find what would be the duty cycle that you have to applied to your MOSFET/Transitor/IGBT. Indeed according to the mode, the transfer function Vout/Vin is not the same.

You will see that with your circuit, you have to have a very low duty cycle to regulate your output voltage correctly (which is impossible) (As Reroute said). With the previous formula and in function of the components that you have and what you are able to adjust on your program you will be able to do a better regulation. I do not remember what are the best operating conditions of a boost converter, but I suggest you to work in CCM. Nevertheless I will consider the DCM case as you operates for the moment in this mode:

$$\frac{Vout}{Vin} = 1+\frac{Vin*D*D*T}{2*L*Iload}$$ where D is the duty cycle and T the period

For better understanding, I suggest you to simulate your circuit on LTspice

Good luck !

Comment: how do i know if my boost converter work with DCM or CCM , i know that i should work with CCM ,but I dont know how i apply this in my circuit.

Comment: Your Load is the 1 kOhm resistor. So if you want an output of 12V, you will have a current according to the Ohm's Law to 12mA flowing through your load. If you want your converter to work in CCM you need that the  limit load current $$Ilim$$ be inferior to your output load current, ie, 12 mA. You can increase your inductance for example. You have to do some math, if you want to adjust correctly your inductance (or other parameters) in function of the duty cycle that you want to have. Firstly, I think you should fixe the duty cycle that you want and then calcul the other parameters

Comment: You will find more informations here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter

Comment: If you think the answer helps you, you can set it as "answer" by clicking on the "accept button" which is located at the top left corner of the post.

Comment: So I have to take care of that the I_lim< I_load?

Comment: Yes ! I_lim is the current limit between DCM and CCM. If your current load is lower than I_lim, your boost will work in DCM whereas if your current load is superior to I_lim, the boost will work in CCM. I

Comment: I did recalculations and those are the values ​​I put in my circuit (boost converter) :          L= 100u ,C=100u ,D.C=0.8, Rload=100 ohm, and mosfet FQP30N06L   , but now suddenly the resistor heats up and even burns, why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and I changed the Vin = 3V , I Want to get Vout=12V , but I didnt get it i get 10V and the resistor start to burn and I stop it

Comment: Hello, I do not know if your calculs are right. About your resistor problem, it is possible that your resistor is not sized for the power that the resistor have to dissipate. If you have Vout = 12V and an resistor of 100 Ohm, the resistor have to dissipate 12²/100 = 1.44W which can be sufficient for burning a resistor. What are your resistors ?  Otherwise you can parallel resistors for lowering the power that they have to dissipate. Example if you use two 200 Ohm resistors for having 100 Ohm, one resistor will dissipate 0.72W.

Comment: i have the small resistors ,I mean the regular resistors

Comment: I check that they are 1/8 Watt

Comment: You can parallel 12 1/8W resistors  if you want to keep a load equal to 100 Ohm otherwise you may increase your inductance or increase your frequency in order to have less constraints to do on your load. You will succeed !

Comment: ok ,  thank  you!! , Just for sure , I made the calculations due to TEXAS INSTRUMENTS

Comment: and I am using the raspberri pi microcontroller , in the pdf file TEXAS INSTRUMENTS they note that the equations to calculate built with an IC ,

Comment: I did not get your link " TEXAS INSTRUMENTS"

Comment: [link]http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva372c/slva372c.pdf

Comment: Well, Texas Instrument did really nice artciles. I didn't read this document, but if you follow every steps it should work ;) If you have some points that you do not understand, you can tell me, but I suggest you to do an other post. Other persons than me will have the possibility to answer to your questions. And many persons in this forum are better than me ;)  If you think my first answer helps you, please click on the "accept answer" which is located at the top left corner of the post. Thank you :)

Comment: hey Jess, I've been debating whether to ask you about something I've been stuck on for a 3 weeks , I improved my converter I recalculated and set other values ​​according to the new input voltage, changed frequency and put a 100 ohm variable and 25 ohm column, the thing I do not understand is that I do simulation in LTspice I get the output voltage I want (9- 12V) ,But in reality for a minimum 25 ohm resistor I only get 6V and for a maximum resistor which is 125 I get 12V.

Comment: Hi, I recommand you to do an other post and show your LTspice simulation and show again your circuit ;) Also it would be nice to take a picture of your real circuit.

Comment: Spent all that time writing an answer and replying to OPs questions and didn't even get an upvote? Geez. Have one on me. :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is how much energy is stored in your inductor each switching cycle vs how much load you have on your output

Most boost converters driving a small load would enter a hiccup mode where it only pulses once when the voltage gets too low,

In your case your constantly topping up the circuit at 50KHz, so you may need to alternate between 0% and 1% for short periods as the voltage falls, or as the other commenter suggested, increase the amount of load.